# target specific slide in carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried one of the solutions i found for targeting the specific photo in the page carousel with the modal carousel but i couldn’t get it to work. What am i overlooking? something small? Here is my code:

```
<div id = "photo-1" class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Saturday May 09, 2015</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="may0915" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#gallery" class = "thumbnail" data-slide-to = "0"> <img src="last-night/saturdayday01.jpg" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#photomodalsaturday" alt = "photo-carosel"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#gallery" class = "thumbnail" data-slide-to = "2"> <img src="last-night/saturday1402.jpg" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#photomodalsaturday" alt = "photo-carosel"></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#photomodalsaturday" data-toggle ="modal" class = "thumbnail3"> <img src="last-night/thursdaymay1401.jpg" alt = "photo-carosel"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#photomodalsaturday" data-toggle ="modal" class = "thumbnail"> <img src="last-night/saturdaymay1402.jpg" alt = "photo-carosel"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#may0915" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#may0915" data-slide="next">›</a>
                     </div>
                        <!--/myCarousel-->
                    </div>
                 <!--/well-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class = "modal fade" id = "photomodalsaturday" role= "dialoge">
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
      <div class= "modal-header">
          <h4>We Love HipHop</h4>
          <p>Saturday May 14, 2015</p>
        <div id = “saturday-carousel" class = "carousel slide">

            <ol class = "carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target = “#saturday-carousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
                <li data-target = “#saturday-carousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
                <li data-target = “#saturday-carousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div id = “saturdaycarousel" class = "carousel-inner">
                <div class = "item active">
                    <img src="last-night/saturdaymay1401.jpg" alt = "beach" class= "img-responsive" >              
                </div>

                <div class = "item">
                    <img src="last-night/saturdaymay1402.jpg" alt = "beach" class= "img-responsive" >              
                </div>

                <div class = "item">
                    <img src="last-night/saturdaymay1403.jpg" alt = "beach" class= "img-responsive" >              
                </div>
            </div>
                 <a class="left carousel-control" href=“#saturday-carousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href=“#saturday-carousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class = "modal-footer">
              <a id = "stopSound3" class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss = "modal">CLOSE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "target", make a specific img active? Can you put the code in a fiddle?

Comment: i want to make the same picture in the modal carousel appear when you click it in the page carousel.